# Is dual WAN load balancing possible for traffic to/from a webserver

Tags: load-balancer, load-balancing

We are currently hosting our website onsite and are maxing out the up and down speeds of the 50/5 mbps bandwidth provided by our ISP. They can not offer us a higher bandwidth connection but they can offer us a second connection at the same bandwith.

Is it possible to load balance those two connections for a reasonable cost/setup? I understand that no single user will gain the benefit of both connections but would different external users see a benefit?

We are looking at this router as a possible solution [https://www.amazon.com/Cisco-Systems-Gigabit-Router-RV320K9NA/dp/B00DGH08OC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DGH08OC).

Comment: [Cisco IOS IP Configuration Guide, Release 12.2 Chapter: Configuring Server Load Balancing](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/ip/configuration/guide/fipr_c/1cfsflb.html)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the 50/5 mbps bandwidth provided by our ISP. They can not offer us a higher bandwidth connection but they can offer us a second connection at the same bandwith.

With a traffic ratio like that i'm guessing you are talking about a "broadband" connection, likely cable though possiblly VDSL. Be aware that broadband connections are contended. So even if you can balance the traffic you may or may not get the speedup you desire.

> Is it possible to load balance those two connections for a reasonable cost/setup?

Yes. There are three scenarios.

The best case is if your ISP is highly cooperative. You can have a single pool of IP addresses with the ISP load balancing on their end and your router load balancing on your end.

If your ISP doesn't explicity cooperate but also isn't too careful about ingress filtering you may be able to treat the IPs are one pool on your end even though the ISP is not and load-balance all outgoing traffic.

If your ISP doesn't cooperate and is doing careful ingress filtering then you will need to route traffic to the correct ISP based on it's source address. This can be done using policy routing. You can then give your webserver IP addresses from both blocks and use a DNS round robin to load balance them,